# How do I learn to build practical stuff?

Tags: practical

I am in my 4th semester of a 4-year undergraduate electronics rngineering program. All I have learned so far is lots of theory in courses such as analog electronics circuits, digital electronics circuits, signal processing. All we do in our labs is either use MATLAB to write simple code for doing computations in signal processing or build relatively simple stuff on breadboard-based prototypes. What if I want to build something practical that I can use, like a guitar effects pedal?

Right now, I am learning signal processing, so I want to build something practical related to that. How do I do that? Do I have to learn how to use Arduino or Raspberry Pi for that?

Comment: Art of electronics

Comment: Audio electronics is a rather rewarding entry point. Very simple circuits with simple ubiquitous parts. Can be very nicely combined with a sim tool like LTspice/microcap to see and understand how the circuit behavior translates to listening experience, you learn to debunk tons of audio myths. You can safely blow up a few parts as you go , with all being cheap and low voltage. As you get more experienced you get a feeling for if you want to do power, highspeed analog, low-noise/metrology, something rule heavy (automotive, EMC, aero) or just programming/DSP.

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to *engineer* things, or how to *fabricate* things? Despite what pop culture might have you think, they are very different skills (though fabrication will help you be a better engineer).

Comment: While not exact cross-post, I think it might be fair to point out your similar question on Signal Processing because there may be overlap in answers: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87132/how-can-i-build-something-like-actual-implementation-from-all-these-things-i-am

Comment: What kind of relatively simple stuff have you built?

Comment: You should definitely bring this up to your teachers by the way. Sounds like your course has too much theory and not enough practice. Because your *job* will be building stuff, it's kinda important to have some experience with that. But I ask what you have built because I wonder if they have taught you the skills needed and you don't realize it. Often, complex stuff is just simple stuff, but lots of it.

Comment: I vote to reopen. While there may be some opinions, the good answers that rise to the top will be based on personal experience. Closing this question denies experienced electronics people a mechanism to provide good advice on getting started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for hands on combined with a good text book.

Pick a device you are interested in, then purchase a kit to build it from.  I suggest a kit rather than using a schematic from the internet because a kit will have (most likely) been reviewed and corrected.  A schematic from the internet may have been designed and built once - there may be errors or weak spots in it that weren't discovered.  I say that out of experience.  I post most of the things I build on the internet, and I know that I make mistakes.

Purchase a good soldering iron and simple tools.  It doesn't take a lot. A pair of needle nose pliers, a pair of tweezers, a desoldering bulb or pump.  Make sure to get a soldering iron with a temperature regulator.  Don't start with an unregulated iron or one that regulates the power.  You want one that controls the temperature.  (I started out as a kid with an unregulated iron.  You can learn to use an unregulated iron well, but you will damage things until you get the hang of it.)

Assemble the kit following the directions it comes with.

A good kit will include a schematic diagram as well as the assembly instructions.  It should also include a description of how the device functions.

Assembling the kit will give you a view of what it takes to make a workable device - how things have to be arranged to make a practical, usable device.  Where controls go, where inputs and outputs go, how to connect power, etc.  Pay attention to where things are on the PCB in relation to where they are on the device housing.

Go through the schematic and the functional  description from the kit and identify the functional blocks of the circuit - things like amplifiers, buffers, filters, clippers (if you are building a fuzz box,) etc.  Look them up in a good text book (*The Art of Electronics* is a common recommendation) and read up on how the circuit blocks function and the theory behind them.

Learn by observation how the mechanical parts work.  Learn by comparison with a good text how the circuit works and how it was designed.

Once you've got a little experience, pick out a device you'd like to have.  Break its function down into individual blocks and look up how they work.  Design each block and join them together to make the device.  Build it, try it, find errors, correct the design, make it work.

---

Signal processing is more a question of programming than hardware.  There are many ways to get into it.

A simple way to start is to get a copy of [GNU Radio](https://www.gnuradio.org/).  Despite the name, GNU Radio is not specific to radio signals.  It is perfectly happy to work with audio signals - it can use the soundcard in a PC or a Raspberry Pi for signal input and output.

You can design your signal processing chain using the graphical [GNU Radio Companion](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=What_Is_GNU_Radio) or you can write Python code to chain together the various GNU Radio functions.  You can also combine the two approaches - the "humdrum" setup of input and output in GRC together with a module in Python to carry out whatever complicated processing steps you'd like.

Develop the functions you'd like to carry out using GNU Radio.  Once you know what needs to be done, you can translate them to another language for standalone use or more performance.  You may also consider porting it to a microcontroller and optimizing it to run within that more restricted environment.

---

Whatever approach you choose, keep in mind that it will be a long process.  There is a lot to learn, and a lot of interesting things to build and do.  It can be very rewarding - and very frustrating.

When you try something new, give it your best shot using what you already know and what information you can find on your own.  When you get stuck, ask for help.  Nobody can do or know everything alone - there's simply too much out there.  Ask for help.  It is almost certain that someone has been in a similar spot and can give you suggestions and assistance.

---

Many people will suggest using simulators to learn about electronic circuits.  Pretty much everyone uses them at some point.

Keep in mind that simulators aren't perfect and don't always reflect reality.

You need to have some knowledge of what you expect the circuit to do so that you can judge whether or not the simulator is telling you the truth.

It often helps to have built a real (though simplified) version of a circuit before you try to simulate a more complicated version.

---

One of the most useful tools for electronics is an oscilloscope.

As a kid, I owned a functional oscilloscope before I owned a good multimeter.  I bought the 'scope at a garage sale for just a few dollars.  It wasn't accurate, but it let me see what was really going on in the circuits I built.

I find that it is often really useful to trace a signal through a circuit to see what is going on.  Linear regulator putting out the wrong voltage? Oh, the output is oscillating.  You can't (directly) find that with a multimeter.

It doesn't have to be a good scope, or a new scope. It just needs to be functional.  Mostly you don't need a precise measurement when trouble shooting.  If your switching regulator is running at 101KHz instead of the intended 100KHz, well, so what.  It's more important to know that it is switching at all and that it isn't switching at a completely wrong frequency.

A used scope that you can afford now is better than a brand new one that you have to save up for a year or two to buy.  It won't have all the snazzy functions, but it will give you insight **now.**

The inexpensive little scopes that you can buy on Amazon and other places generally aren't worth it.  The input range (voltage) is too low and the bandwidth (frequency range) is too low to really be useful.

A used professional scope that is twenty or thirty years old shouldn't cost much more than the new cheap junk but it will serve you better.

Comment: You can find reasonably priced oscilloscope kits to practice building, which fills both goals (example: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08DJ1YS99/). But unfortunately, I think this advice misses the mark.

Comment: I have one of the cheap scopes that are sold as kits, but sometimes they ship a fully assembled unit, which defeats the purpose of a soldering and assembly aid. The specs are reasonable enough with 200 kHz bandwidth and sensitivity from 10 mV/div to 5V/div (50V total) with a 1x probe, and a 10x probe extends that to 500V (although I wouldn't want to use it on anything more than 120 VRMS). My first scope was a 1940's era Triumph https://www.oscilloscopemuseum.org/oscilloscope-triumph-830-s2024.html, and then an HP140A (1960s vintage) https://www.hpmemoryproject.org/wb_pages/wall_b_page_02.htm.

Comment: @PStechPaul:  My current scope is a Telequipment D43 from 1965.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one way: Purchase a soldering iron, a multimeter, and preferably an oscilloscope. Then find an end use that interests you and start designing. A guitar pedal sounds like an ideal first project. It is unlikely to require an MCU like a Rasberry Pie or Arduino.

But you need to realize that your future in this field will require a lifetime of learning. I started in electronics in the early 1970s when the 7400 series of ICs was new and hi tech. I retired a few years back. Along the way I had to learn computer programming basics, real time programming, various assembly languages, PLC languages, FPLA programming, SQL, HTML, Javascript, C++, Fortran, Pascal. Java, C# and a host of design methodologies and development tools.

Best of luck with your career. The only certainty is that the development tools you are using today will be superceded in 10 years time. Electronics is a fascinating and great career (and reasonably lucrative), but you do need a passionate attitude to keep up with the latest trends.

Answer (score 4):

If you will be seriously pursuing a career in electronics engineering, I think you need to:

1. Determine what sort of projects interest you most, and hopefully be excited about
2. List the type of circuits for which you are most competent.
3. Choose several projects and develop a design, including schematics, parts list (BOM), and PCB layout. And determine what sort of enclosure or packaging will be needed.
4. If this will require a microcontroller (and most things these days do), choose a platform, and start developing a flow chart and software.
5. Build a prototype and perform rigorous testing

You already seem interested in a guitar effects device, so search the internet and find similar devices, perhaps offered as a kit or tutorial, and seek to understand the concepts and try to find ways to improve the design.

It may be difficult to find something that has not already been designed and built, but there may be certain niche areas where it may be possible to do something unique. Meanwhile, have fun and learn as much as you can, and gain experience.